# do I need to manually tag "latest" when pushing to docker public repository?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Suppose I have an image `me/mystuff:v0.0.1`

I find if I push it to the repository:

```
docker push me/mystuff:v0.0.1
```

`latest` is not created, and on a pull from another machine it will complain, e.g.

```
ssh me@faraway
(faraway)  $ docker run -it me/mystuff /bin/bash
```

will result in a not found error for `me/mystuff:latest`

I can add the latest tag and push explicitly to the public repository:

```
docker login me
docker tag me/mystuff:v0.0.1 me/mystuff:latest
docker push me/mystuff:latest
```

and then from another machine:

```
docker pull me/mystuff
```

will work because latest exists.

I am also finding that once latest exists, it does not auto update when a new numbered version is pushed.

Can I somehow eliminate this step of manually tagging latest and have latest automatically point to the latest numbered version?

Or is it there for a reason, like allowing the separation of development versions (tagged with a vN.N.N only) from the production version (tagged latest)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The latest is just the default value of the tag if none is specified. If you push a tagged image it does not replace the current image tagged with latest.

Comment: is there a command to push it as an tag AND as latest? or do i need two commands for this? eg: docker push foo/bar:v1 docker push foo/bar

Comment: NOTE: pushing without a tag (ie: `docker push foo/bar`) pushes all the local images marked with repo foo/bar. If one of those has no tag, it'll presumably push a 'latest' tag (as @Usman says). If all your local images are tagged, only those tags get pushed (which may not include 'latest'). Note you can easily create multiple tags on local images as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25214186/420867), eg: create a local 'latest' tag that you can then push.

Comment: Surely `docker tag me/mystuff:v0.0.1 me/mystuff:latest` would work and you don't need two tags.

Comment: Also, Docker is smart enough that if you push two tags, and they both have the same underlying hashes, it recognizes it and simply adds the second tag name.