# How does Docker handle different image versions for local repositories?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

A little while ago I set up a local repository for some of my custom containers, they all seem to work fine and when they're running if I issue a `docker image ls` I can see the repository image and the tag is `latest`

Now, I recently made a chance to one of those images, and when I pushed it to the repository I tagged it `:v1.0` in an effort to have some sort of versioning.

The problem is that it seems like when I try to deploy a container based on that image name, when it defaults to `latest` that doesn't mean the `v1.0` image, despite that one being the most recent one pushed.

Did I mess up by not tagging my original images with a version, or is there a different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `latest` is just the default tag name for when you don't supply one. You'll have to explicitly tag latest (or explicitly not use a tag) if you plan on pushing multiple tags at once. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643017/do-i-need-to-manually-tag-latest-when-pushing-to-docker-public-repository) and [here](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)

Comment: Thanks for those links, they didn't show up in my research earlier. Does that mean I should delete my current `image` in the repository if I didn't tag it with a version when I originally uploaded it?